# Angular js :How to achieve mouse event from directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a sample code in controller

```
    $scope.phoneMouseOver = function () {
        $scope.phoneMask = '123-456-7890';
        $scope.phonePlaceholder = '';
    };

    $scope.phoneBlur = function (e) {
        var isFocused = (document.activeElement === e.target);
        if (!isFocused && $scope.data.phone === '') {
            $scope.phoneMask = '';
            $scope.phonePlaceholder = '123-456-7890';
        }
    };
```

HTML

```
<input ui-mask="{{phoneMask}}"
                        ng-mouseover="phoneMouseOver()"
                        ng-mouseleave="phoneMouseLeave($event)"
                        ng-blur="phoneBlur($event)"
                        ui-options='{ "clearOnBlur": false ,"eventsToHandle": [ "input", "keyup", "click", "focus", "mouseover" ] },' ui-mask-placeholder-char
                        ui-mask-placeholder
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control input-phone"
                        ng-model="data.phone">
```

If it is possible to achieve this from directive instead of using angular attribute?

Comment: where is the HTML ? and yes this is possibly posiible. using `link` function in directive

Comment: I have updated HTML ^^

Comment: By using link is it possible to to handle all mouse event of particular element